# React's setState doesn't change state and update component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm calling console.log as a callback from setState and it seems like setState doesn't work. I'm trying to write a function which takes state defined  like this:

```
this.state = {
     ...this.props.substate
};
```

this.props.substate is an array of objects, so I'm transforming it to object.
Here is a function that transforms state back to array, removes last element and then transforms array into object:

```
handleClickRem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state);

    const arrayFromState = Object.values(this.state);
    console.log(arrayFromState);

    const newArray = arrayFromState.slice(0, -1);
    console.log('newArray',newArray);

    const newState = {...newArray};
    console.log(newState);
    //newState is exactly what I want it to be

    this.setState(newState, () => console.log(this.state));
};
```

All console logs works perfectly apart from the last one. I'm also checking state in render(), but it also seems to show no change of state.

I've done similarly a function, which adds elements to state and it works perfectly.

I'll be very thankful for help and patience :)

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo can you tell me more about worst practice that you see? Maybe it is the source of my problems

Comment: You can read more about setting props as state here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor
Define your component state. If you see that the component needs props as state probably this component should be only presentational and the parent component should implement the logic.
Note: try to call setState this way.. this.setState({...this.state, newState}); and remember that setState is async! So you will see the new state later.

Comment: can you show me what's the result of `console.log(this.state);` ? I would need to know what's in your state at the beginning

Comment: The result of `console.log(this.state)` is:
`{0: {…}, 1: {…}}
0: {company: "", jobTitle: "", dateFrom: "", dateTo: ""}
1: {company: "", jobTitle: "", dateFrom: "", dateTo: ""}
__proto__: Object`